# Searching a string for " possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm searching a string for "score" but I don't want it to return when it comes across "score_time"

```
range = [substring rangeOfString: @"score"];
```

Is what I am using.

But if i could search for '"score"' it would work. But I cant use " as a part of my search because the compiler gets confused.

```
range = [substring rangeOfString: @""score:""];
```

Is there someway to tell it to include the " in the search?

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try escaping it like so `"\"score\""`.

Answer (score 5):

```
range = [substring rangeOfString: @"\"score:\""];
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, escape the quotes with `\`:

```
range = [substring rangeOfString:@"\"score\""];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([substring rangeOfString:@"\"score:\""].location != NSNotFound) {
    // "score" was found
else {
    // "score was not found
}
```